# Retuning empty webpages when writing the contents of wget in Ruby

Tags: ruby, download, wget

I am trying to a save a website to an HTML file using Ruby.
When I open the file, the website is empty.

Currently trying:

```
doc = system("wget -r -l 1 http://google.com")
my_file = 'google.html'  
f = File.open(my_file, 'w')  
f.write(doc)  
f.close
```

I can get it working using Nokogiri, but I'm trying to keep it as simplistic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) instead of any external utility to download pages in Ruby.

But if you must, read [this article](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html) on calling programs from Ruby.

Basically you must call `(backtick)wget ...(backtick)` (sorry about the parser) or `%x[wget ...]` instead of `system` if you're interested in the program's output.